# How to convert SQL statement to LINQ?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, case, distinct

My problem is to extract distinct PartId with another 4 different columns type boolean just like the SQL query does. Picture 1 presents output what I desire. And the question is how can I solve the same problem using LINQ and EF Core if we assume that we use dBcontext as default. What is more assume that object ApprovalNumberRecord  is DbSet and has navigation to Part and Approval object.

```
SELECT
    B.PartId
    ,Sum(Case when B.ApprovalName = 'R-67' then 1 Else 0 End) as [R-67]
    ,Sum(Case when B.ApprovalName = 'R115' then 1  Else 0 End) as [R115]
    ,Sum(Case when B.ApprovalName = 'LPG-D' then 1  Else 0 End) as [LPG-D]
    ,Sum(Case when B.ApprovalName = 'CNG-D' then 1  Else 0 End) as [CNG-D]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         anr.PartId
         ,a.ApprovalName
         ,anr.IsVisible
         ,p.[Description]
     FROM 
         ApprovalNumberRecord AS anr
     LEFT JOIN
         Parts AS p ON anr.PartId = p.Id
     LEFT JOIN
         Approvals AS a ON anr.ApprovalId = a.Id) AS B 
GROUP BY
    B.PartId
```

[Output of SQL statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z980e.png)

And this is the inner SELECT output:

[OUTPUT of inner SQL statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1gQf.png)

Underneath database models:

ApprovalNumberRecord class:

```
... //other fields and properties

public Part Part { get; set; }
public Approval Approval { get; set; }
```

Part class:

```
public Producer Producer{ get; set; }
public Category Category { get; set; }
public ICollection<ApprovalNumberRecord> ApprovalNumberRecords { get; set; }
```

Approval class:

`none navigation objects inside`

Comment: Please show how you mapped the database model to EF classes. We need to see navigation properties. Also, [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold I thought it would be clear and transparent enough to ask a question properly. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var innerQuery =
  from anr in dbContext.ApprovalNumberRecords
  let p = anr.Part
  let a = anr.Approval
  select new { anr.PartId, a?.ApprovalName, anr.IsVisible, p?.Description };

var groupQuery =
  from B in innerQuery
  group B by B.PartId into g
  select new {
    PartId = g.Key,
    R_67 = g.Sum(x => x.ApprovalName == 'R-67' ? 1 : 0),
    R115 = g.Sum(x => x.ApprovalName == 'R111' ? 1 : 0),
    LPG_D = g.Sum(x => x.ApprovalName == 'LPG-D' ? 1 : 0),
    CNG_D = g.Sum(x => x.ApprovalName == 'CNG-D' ? 1 : 0)
  };
```

Comment: `PartId : ` should be `PartId =`, same for others.

Comment: @AmyB it is what I exactly want it in my question. The only one thing what the VS compiler notice as error _CS8072_ was the fact that anonymous record for `innerQuery` cannot contain null operator for `a?.ApprovalName` and `p?.Description`: _"An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator"_. I have another question what about if I want to see in `groupQuery` a `Part.Name` and `anr.IsVisible` column?